# To execute a generator

Tags: python

Suppose I create a generator of the following form:

```
e=[(lambda x:2*x)(x) for x in range(10)]
```

The way to execute and accumulate the results would be :

```
list([(lambda x:2*x)(x) for x in range(10)])
```

However,if I am actually performing a cleaning-up operation(maybe file deletion) as follows:

```
[(lambda x:db.delete(x.path()))(x) for x in self.candidates if x is not None]
```

What is the convention to execute this - a list really looks odd in this scenario as there is no result I am interested in?

Comment: Those aren't generators - those are all list comprehensions using lambdas.

Comment: The lambda is not even needed actually.

Comment: Do you not like a plain old for-statement with a nested if-statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a plain-old for loop.

```
for x in self.candidates:
    if x is not None:
        db.delete(x.path())
```

List comprehensions and lambdas are needless sophistication here, it's just making your code less readable.

If, in a more appropriate use-case, you actually need to consume a generator you can do this by nomming it into a zero-length deque:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> import collections
>>> g = (print(x) for x in 'potato')
>>> _ = collections.deque(g, maxlen=0)
p
o
t
a
t
o
```

Comment: I'm not even sure why he used lambda.